# Flutter List state losing state

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, state-management, flutter-bloc

List state is empty when I submit.
I am using flutter bloc to manage state in my application and I am storing a List of Maps in scores state. The problem I am having is state.scores is empty when I submit. Though I can immediately access HandleScoreInputEvent where is set.  I am not mutating state directly and I believe I am doing everything right to the best of my knowledge. Here is my code.
//State

```
class ExamState {
 
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> scores;

  ExamState({
   
    this.scores = const [],
  });
  ExamState copyWith({
    
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> scores = const [],
  }) {
    return ExamState(
     
      scores: scores,
    );
  }
}

And here is the event handler in the ExamBloc
```

List<Map<String, dynamic>>? scores;

```
class ExamBloc extends Bloc<ExamEvent, ExamState> {
  final ExamRepository? repo = ExamRepository();

  ExamBloc() : super(ExamState()) {
   

    on<HandleScoreInputEvent>((event, emit) {
      final existingIndex = state.scores
          .indexWhere((score) => score['studentId'] == event.studentId);

      if (existingIndex != -1) {
        final updatedScore = {
          ...state.scores[existingIndex],
          if (event.marks != null) 'marks': event.marks,
          if (event.comment != null) 'comment': event.comment,
        };

        final List<Map<String, dynamic>> updatedScores =
            List.from(state.scores);

        updatedScores[existingIndex] = updatedScore;
        emit(state.copyWith(scores: updatedScores));
        scores = updatedScores;
      } else {
        final score = {
          'studentId': event.studentId,
          'classId': event.classId,
          'examId': event.examId,
          'subjectId': event.subjectId,
          if (event.marks != null) 'marks': event.marks,
          if (event.comment != null) 'comment': event.comment,
        };
        final updatedScores = [...state.scores, score];
        updatedScores.add(score);

        emit(state.copyWith(scores: updatedScores));
      }
     
    });

  

    on<ShowExamEvent>((event, emit) async {
      emit(state.copyWith(formStatus: FormSubmitting()));
      try {
        final res = await repo!.showExam(examId: event.examId);
        if (res.statusCode == 200) {
          var responseJson = jsonDecode(res.body);
          ExamModel exam = ExamModel.fromJson(responseJson);
          emit(state.copyWith(exam: exam));
          emit(state.copyWith(formStatus: SubmissionSuccess()));
        } else {
          emit(state.copyWith(
              formStatus: ApiRequestNotSuccessFul(res.body.toString())));
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
        emit(state.copyWith(formStatus: SubmissionFailed(e as Exception)));
      }
    });

   

    

    on<SubmitStudentExamResult>((event, emit) async {
      emit(state.copyWith(formStatus: FormSubmitting()));
      print(state.scores);

      try {
        final res = await repo!.saveExamResult(
          data: scores,
        );
        if (res.statusCode == 201) {
          emit(state.copyWith(formStatus: SubmissionSuccess()));
        } else {
          emit(state.copyWith(
              formStatus: ApiRequestNotSuccessFul(res.body.toString())));
        }
      } catch (e) {
        emit(state.copyWith(formStatus: SubmissionFailed(e as Exception)));
      }
    });

    
  }
}
Up to here its working as expected. I can access the state with all values being added. However, in the event I am submitting data to the server, state.scores is empty. Here is the event that is handling submission to the server.
```

on((event, emit) async {
print(state.scores); //empty

});

```
I have been stuck here for three days now. I just seem not figure out what is actually going wrong. Here is part of my view. I am debouncing user input to reduce uncessary state emissions.


  final _debounceSubject = BehaviorSubject<String>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _debounceSubject.stream
        .debounceTime(
            Duration(milliseconds: 700)) // Adjust the debounce time as needed
        .listen((value) {
      // Handle the debounced value (e.g., update scores)

      // Call _handleMarksChange only if _currentStudentId is available
      _handleMarksChange(
        value,
        // No comment in this scenario
      );
    });
  }

  List scores = [];
  String? _currentStudentId;

  void _handleMarksChange(String value) {
    // Update the BLoC state with the new marks value
    int? marksValue = int.tryParse(value);
    if (marksValue != null) {
      //then input is a number for marks
      context.read<ExamBloc>().add(HandleScoreInputEvent(
          marks: int.parse(value),
          studentId: _currentStudentId!,
          classId: widget.classId,
          examId: widget.examId,
          subjectId: widget.subjectId,
          comment: null));
    } else {
      context.read<ExamBloc>().add(HandleScoreInputEvent(
          marks: null,
          studentId: _currentStudentId!,
          classId: widget.classId,
          examId: widget.examId,
          subjectId: widget.subjectId,
          comment: value));
    }
  }

   Widget _submitButton(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ExamBloc, ExamState>(builder: (context, state) {
      return PrimaryButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (_key.currentState!.validate()) {
            context.read<ExamBloc>().add(SubmitStudentExamResult());
          }
        },
        label: state.formStatus is FormSubmitting
            ? CircularProgressIndicator(
                valueColor: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
              )
            : const Text('Save'),
      );
    });
  }
```

Any help please?

Comment: please submit full code

Comment: That may be too cumbersome. The posted snippet is the source of the problem. Other part of the code serves different purpose and is independent of from this.

Comment: The posted snippet may be not the source of the problem.
how do you create ExamBloc?
there is pissibility that this are different instance of ExamBloc.

Comment: I have updated the bloc section in the code and included the entire bloc class.

Comment: Can you paste the code where you are accessing the list state in the ui file.